# code coverage python from external libraries

Tags: python, code-coverage

Currently am trying to implement an automation testing tool for python projects, however I figure out a problem would like to ask if it is possible to collect the code coverage from external libraries using Coverage module?, as far as I know the coverage module report only the code coverage within the project.

example:

test_code.py

```
import random


def test_rand()

  assert random.randint(0,10) == 5
```

in this case how can I collect code coverage from random module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`coverage run --help` includes these lines:

```
  -L, --pylib           Measure coverage even inside the Python installed
                        library, which isn't done by default.
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yeah this is what I was looking for :)